# Apache Cordova for Visual Studio Android project issue

Tags: android, apache, android-emulator, visual-studio-cordova

I have an html game that works perfectly on Windows Phone.
I tried making a version for Android, and it works very well on the Ripple emulator, in an Apache Cordova for Visual Studio project. But if in Visual Studio I set "Android Emulator" as the emulator instead of Ripple, nothing works: the "drawimage" function does not draw anything at all, the html audio element does not play music, and it is very slow. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you are using VS 2015, try the VS Android emulator is that helps? Have you tried running your app on an actual android device?

Comment: I can't open my project with VS 2015 because it's incompatible: this is probably because my project was created using the "Apache Cordova Apps" template, and such template does not exist in VS 2015.

Comment: In an actual Android device there are the same issues as in the emulators.

Comment: If you're using OpenGL 3.0, it is not supported in the VS emulator. See this doc: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/11/12/introducing-visual-studio-s-emulator-for-android.aspx. Also, the emulator will generally work better with VS2015, but you would need to update the project structure (often easier to start with a new Blank template).